# On blur of ASP.NET form field, call validator(s) on that one field

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I have a form that has some standard ASP.NET validators and some custom validators.

I know how to force the whole page to validate.

But how on blur of a form field can I force the `validator(s)` that are looking at the field fire, not all validations on the page.

I expect I am missing some little trick. :(

Comment: Actually I think I might have found my answer... if i get it all to work I'll post my solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well looks like I answered my own question, with some help from George, and the Intertubes.

After seeing this [post](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/validation/client-sidevalidation.aspx):  I looked at the DOM in Firebug and found the array of Validators. Then it was a matter of getting the right ones, and calling the `ValidatorValidate(validator)` method.

```
function callMyValidators() {
    // Clean Up Infragistics Ids
    var cleanid = this.id.replace(/^igtxt/i,"");

    for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        if (Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate === cleanid) {
            ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function: ValidatorValidate(val)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: Nice, but do you have a way to get all validator(s) obj associated with the field dynamically. I don't want to hard code these scripts. I want the beautiful solution ( which I might not get )